# The request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found angular+spring

Tags: java, angular, spring, typescript, httprequest

I'm trying to upload a file recently downloaded with Angular2 to Spring API Rest.

The problem is (display on spring app)...

> The request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
>
> at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.(FileUploadBase.java:831)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:256)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:280)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2869)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3216)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1137)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]

On the client side, the request is sent with "multipart/form-data" as content-type.

How can I fix it ?

*fileDownloaderService*

```
upload(file) {
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file);
    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', this.urlUpload, file, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'}),
      reportProgress: true
    });
    return this.http.request(req);
  }
```

*app.component*

```
  upload() {
     let file = this.generate_dummy_file(50000000);
     this.downloader.upload(file).subscribe( event => {
        if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
        } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          console.log('File is completly uploaded!');
        }
      });


    }

  generate_dummy_file(size) {
    return new Blob([new ArrayBuffer(size)], {type: 'multipart/form-data'});
  };
```

*And spring side*

```
@PostMapping("/uploadFile")
    public UploadFileResponse uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        return ...;
    }
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ,

```
 const formData = new FormData();
 formData.append("file", file);
 formData.append("reportProgress", true);
```

use httpclient,

```
 return this.httpclient.post(this.urlUpload, formData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you set Content-Type? If so, please remove it.

```
headers:{
        "Content-Type":"multipart/form-data", // remove it
},
```

Front End:

```
 const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);
    formData.append("reportProgress", "true");

return this.http.post<void>(this.API_URL + '/upload', formData);
```

backend end :

```
 @Operation(description = "Upload File")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "201", description = "File Uploaded successfully"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Problem during file upload ")
    })
    @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void upload(@RequestPart("file") final MultipartFile file) {
        //action;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Are you actually sending `FormData` to your server?

Try wrapping the file in a `FormData` object for the `HttpClient` to automatically add the multipart boundaries.

```
upload(file) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', this.urlUpload, formData, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'}),
      reportProgress: true
    });
    return this.http.request(req);
  }
```

Comment: Nothing change, still `the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found`. My file don't come from a form. Maybe it's the cause ? I add more informations to my question.